# if cell has a specified value then call specified sub else call another sub

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, cell

I have two Excel files which have similar layouts and similar cell values in their first Worksheets, only difference is that one of them has a value "Plant" in G6 and the other one has it in E6. The user should pick one of These files, which i have already written as code so that is no Problem, i only Need to put an if else Statement which checks if the cell G6 of the selected file has value "Plant" then it will call a Sub PlantG6 and else it should call Sub PlantE6.

```
   If Workbooks("selectedexcelfile.xlms").Sheets(1).Range("G6").Value = "Plant"
   Then Call PlantE6
   Else...
```

I know this code is wrong so i just wanted to get the right code for this.

Comment: What error are you getting? if it's "Index out of range" then you aren't properly refering to the workbook.

Comment: When you want to check if the (open) workbook has the value "Plant" in the right sheet??? When you open the file? when you change the file?? From other workbook??? Please amplify you questions, saying in more detail, what you want, how you tried to do it, and what errors you have, also how you tried to fixed. And we will be glad to help you. Please read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: is it as simple as `.xlms` rather than `.xlsm`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

    If Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G6").Value = "Plant" Then
        Call PlantG6
    Else
        Call PlantE6
    End If

End Sub
```